# changing multiple dropdown items and their inputs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to make a query builder and I have a simple dropdown list which when added, creates an input text or another dropdown list as shown in below fiddle (simplified by cutting the relevant parts of the code):

https://jsfiddle.net/12aLc85q/

In the first added table row, I can manipulate the boxes in every way, but when I add a second one, it doesn't change. I'm not that experienced in js but I know that I put the change event inside my .add function however I couldn't find any other way to make it work even like this faulty way.
Any idea what I am missing here?

and heres the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{

    var main_search_type = 'summary_results';
    var count = 0;
    var and_or_count = 0;

    $(document).on('click', '.add', function ()
    {
        $(function()
        {
            $("#options").change(function()
            {
                console.log($(this).find(":selected").val())

                if ($(this).find(":selected").data("rate") != "Duplicated")
                {
                    $("#item_id").replaceWith
                    (
                        '<input type="text" name="item_name" id = "item_id" class="form-control item_name"  placeholder="Phlyum Name"'+'>'
                    );
                    $("#item_id").attr("placeholder", $(this).find(":selected").data("rate"));

                }
                else
                {
                    $("#item_id").replaceWith
                    (
                        '<select id="item_id" name="item_name" class="form-control">' +
                        '<option value="true">True</option>' +
                        '<option value="false">False</option>'
                    );
                }

            });
        });

        var html = '';
        if (main_search_type == "summary_results")
        {

        html += '<tr>';
            html +=
                '<td><select name="summary_results" id="options" class="form-control">' +
                '<option placeholder="Phylum Name" name="summary_results" data-rate = "Phylum Name" value="phylum">Phylum</option>' +
                '<option data-rate = "Genus Name" name="summary_results" value="genus">Genus</option>' +'<option data-rate = "Duplicated" value="organism">Organism</option>'
                '</select></td>'
                count++;
        }
       
        if(count != 0)
        {
        html += '<td><input type="text" name="item_name" id = "item_id" class="form-control item_name"  placeholder="Phlyum Name"'+'></td>';
        html += '</tr>';
        $('tbody').append(html);
        }
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <br />
    <div class="container">
      <h4 align="center">Select Main Categories</h4>
        <form method="POST" id="insert_form", name="insert_form_name">
        <div class="table-repsonsive">
          <table class="table table-bordered" id="item_table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Search Option</th>
                <th>Enter Search Term</th>
                <th><button type="button" name="add" class="btn btn-success btn-xs add"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add Term</button></th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
          </table>
        <input type='hidden' name='db_types' id='db_types'>
          <div align="center">
              <span id="error"></span>
          </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: If i click on add term, and select different options from dropdown list, the text box part changes. If i add another term again, then when i select different options, the text box doesn't change, I want it to change as well like the first added term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have duplicated IDs. Hence, I suggest to use the duplicated IDs (i.e.: options and item_id) as class name.

Moreover, don't add and event listner on document click. Use instead a delegated format.

The snippet:

```js
var main_search_type = 'summary_results';
var count = 0;
var and_or_count = 0;

$(document).on('click', '.add', function () {
    var html = '';
    if (main_search_type == "summary_results") {
        html += '<tr>';
        html +=
                '<td><select name="summary_results" class="form-control options">' +
                '<option placeholder="Phylum Name" name="summary_results" data-rate = "Phylum Name" value="phylum">Phylum</option>' +
                '<option data-rate = "Genus Name" name="summary_results" value="genus">Genus</option>' +'<option data-rate = "Duplicated" value="organism">Organism</option>'
        '</select></td>'
        count++;
    }

    if(count != 0) {
        html += '<td><input type="text" name="item_name"  class="form-control item_name item_id"  placeholder="Phlyum Name"'+'></td>';
        html += '</tr>';
        $('tbody').append(html);
    }
});

$(document).on('change', 'select.options', function() {
    console.log($(this).find(":selected").val())

    if ($(this).find(":selected").data("rate") != "Duplicated") {
        $(this).closest('td').next().find('.item_id').replaceWith(
                '<input type="text" name="item_name"  class="form-control item_name item_id"  placeholder="Phlyum Name"'+'>'
        );
        $(this).closest('td').next().find('.item_id').attr("placeholder", $(this).find(":selected").data("rate"));

    } else {
        $(this).closest('td').next().find('.item_id').replaceWith(
                '<select  name="item_name" class="form-control item_id">' +
                '<option value="true">True</option>' +
                '<option value="false">False</option>'
        );
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br />
<div class="container">
    <h4 align="center">Select Main Categories</h4>
    <form method="POST" id="insert_form", name="insert_form_name">
        <div class="table-repsonsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered" id="item_table">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Search Option</th>
                    <th>Enter Search Term</th>
                    <th><button type="button" name="add" class="btn btn-success btn-xs add"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add Term</button></th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody></tbody>
            </table>
            <input type='hidden' name='db_types' id='db_types'>
            <div align="center">
                <span id="error"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, that delegated format i think i need to learn a bit more. So much for bad learning from this or that code from all over the web:). Thanks for the answer btw, worked like a charm.